# C++ Listview tooltip

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, listview, tooltip

I've got a listview in report view that I'm trying to display tooltips for, different per item.

But I can't get any tooltip to be displayed at all...

Here's what I figured out so far:

```
case LVN_GETINFOTIP:
{
    LPNMLVGETINFOTIP GetInfoTip = (LPNMLVGETINFOTIP) lParam;
    GetInfoTip->pszText = L"TESTING";
    // What do I do now? How do I display the tooltip?
    return 0;
}
```

After I have received the `LVN_GETINFOTIP` message, how do I display the tooltip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are replacing the pointer `pszText`. You need to modify the contents of the memory buffer instead. For example using `StringCchPrintf`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you forget to set **LVS_EX_INFOTIP** ?

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hListView, LVS_EX_INFOTIP  | LVS_EX_LABELTIP);
```

look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexdan/archive/2006/05/16/adding-tooltips-to-a-list-view-control.aspx) for an example

Comment: `LVS_EX_INFOTIP` and `LVS_EX_LABELTIP` are both set.

Answer (score 0):

```
LPNMLVGETINFOTIP pGetInfoTip = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVGETINFOTIP>(pNMHDR);
```

in report mode,at least, you will only get the message when mouse is over the 0th column